# Threading 3d models in Windows Presentation Foundation

Tags: wpf, multithreading, 3d, thread-safety, viewport3d

Is there a tutorial I can look at for Windows Presentation Foundation in using multi-threading to create a model in a non UI-thread and add it to the 3D viewport in the UI-thread?

I'm been having trouble trying to since I been getting errors such as:

> "This API was accessed with arguments from the wrong context."

and

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it."

after trying a lot of methods online.

Am I stuck having to create the items (MeshGeometry3D for triangle meshes) in the UI-Thread and have the non UI-thread invoke it to add items for it?

Comment: I've already tried this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808417/adding-a-child-to-viewport3d-asynchronously-gives-this-api-was-accessed-with-ar

but Application.Current ended up being "null". did tried creating a new thread to create a new Application but it still ended up getting the error "This API was accessed with arguments from the wrong context."

Comment: Have a look at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364. These samples contains 3D with Parallel Processing in most.

Comment: I cannot find one which have creating a model on a different thread from the one with the Viewport in it.

Comment: Found My Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523987/how-can-i-load-several-3d-geometries-in-a-separate-thread-without-running-into-t
you can call MeshGeometry3D.freeze() when the data is complete in the Non-UI thread. and when you go back to the main Thread,you can create a new one with MeshGeometry3D.Clone(). The clone will take off a short time in the main thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I load several 3D geometries in a separate thread without running into thread ownership issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523987/how-can-i-load-several-3d-geometries-in-a-separate-thread-without-running-into-t)